# Periodic and Aperiodic signal properties.

Tags: signal-processing, periodic-functions

I have three question on periodic and aperiodic signal that I have doubt about also I couldn't find the answer on searching so I am asking here.

1. Sum of a periodic and aperiodic signal always be a aperiodic signal?
2. If a signal is periodic will its derivative always be a periodic?
3. If on signal $x(t)$ applying $\lim_{t\to\infty}x'(t)=0$,can we say its aperiodic?Why?(this is question because of this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/891266/478219) )

Please answer with a example

Answer (score 3):

1. No, the sum of a periodic and an aperiodic signal can be periodic. Consider for instance:

   - $f(x)=\sin(x)$, which is a periodic function with period $2\pi$,
   - $g(x)=-\sin(x)+\sin(\sqrt{2}x)$, which is an aperiodic function as
     $\displaystyle \inf_{u,v\in\mathbb{Z}}\{\left|u\sqrt{2}+v\right|\}=0$,
   - $f(x)+g(x) = \sin(\sqrt{2}x)$ is a periodic function of period $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$.
2. Yes, if the derivative of a function $f(x)$ exists, and $f(x)$ is periodic with period $T$, then $f'(x)$ is also periodic with the same period $T$ because, for all $x$ and all integers $k$,
   $$f^\prime(x+kT)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+kT+h)-f(x+kT)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f^\prime(x).$$
3. If a periodic function $f(x)$ satisfies $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. You can prove it using
   $$\left|f(x)\right|=\left|f(x+kT)\right|<\varepsilon_k$$ with
   $\lim_{k\to\infty}\varepsilon_k = 0$ by the definition of the convergence. Therefore, $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer....the third question i asked because of this answer how he is saying after $ \lim_{x\to \infty }f'(x)=0.$ its aperiodic https://math.stackexchange.com/a/891266/478219

Comment: Well, if $f^\prime(x)$ were periodic and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f^\prime(x)=0$, this would imply that  $f^\prime(x)=0$  for all $x$ (using the property shown in your 3rd question). Consequently, $f(x)$ would be a constant function, which is clearly not the case. So they can conclude that $f(x)$ is aperiodic.

Comment: sorry I am not getting. suppose $\lim_{t \to \infty}e^{-t}=0$ then should we say $e^{-t} =0 $ for all $t$?

Comment: please expain to me the third point clearly,use example for that it will me more clear.