# Check proof that $\sin\sqrt{|x|}$ is not periodic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-verification

I want to:

> Prove that $\sin\sqrt{|x|}$ is not periodic

A similar question had already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891233/prove-that-sin-sqrt-x-not-periodic). But the accepted answer uses definition of the derivative. And i'm trying to do it in a "pre-calculus" manner.

Here is my try. By definition of periodic functions:

$$
f(x) = \sin\sqrt{|x|} = \sin\sqrt{|x - T|}
$$

This may be rewritten as:

$$
f(x) = \cases{\sin\sqrt{x}, \; x \ge 0 \\
\sin\sqrt{-x}, \; x < 0
}
$$

On the other hand:

$$
f(x) = \cases{\sin\sqrt{x-T}, \; x-T \ge 0 \iff x \ge T \\
\sin\sqrt{T-x}, \; x-T < 0 \iff x < -T
}
$$

So for the first case i have 
$$\sin\sqrt{x} = \sin\sqrt{x-T}$$, but $\forall{T} > 0, \exists x \ge 0 : x < T$ which contradicts the fact that $x \ge T$. The second case is handled similarly.

Is it valid?

Comment: No this is not valid. If you assume $x>T$ then the fact that there exists real numbers $< T$ is not a contradiction (you have fixed $x$ when making that assumption).

Comment: no, you are comparing different functions with different domains

Comment: For $f(x)$ to be periodic there must exist such $T\ne 0$ that for each $x$ the equality $f(x)=f(x+T)$ holds. As a special case it must hold for $x=0$. Try the $x = 0$ case then – does there exist such non-zero $T$ that $f(0) = f(T) = f(2T) = \ldots =f(nT)$ for each integer $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working at $x\ge T$, so, how can you suppose that exist some $x<T$? It doesn't make sense.

A suggestion could be use the identity:

$$\sin p-\sin q=2\sin\left(\frac{p-q}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{p+q}{2}\right).$$

In your case you have $p=\sqrt{x}$ and $q=\sqrt{x-T}$, for $x\ge T.$ So,

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-T}}{2}=k\pi,\quad k\in \Bbb Z$$ or
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-T}}{2}=\frac \pi 2+k\pi,\quad k\in \Bbb Z$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct. There is no reason to assume that when we are in the first case in the case of $\sin\left(\sqrt{|x|}\right)$, then we are also in the first case in the case of $\sin\left(\sqrt{|x-T|}\right)$ and vice-versa.

It's quite easy to deduce that the function is not periodic from the fact that its zeros form the set$$\left\{n^2\pi^2\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\right\}.$$